# Realm unable to sync data among different devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm

The following is my sync realm configuration.For each device, I install the app data is not synced with them.My realm object server is in AWS ec2

```
 Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("username","password",false);
        SyncUser user = SyncUser.login(syncCredentials, serverUrl());
        SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, realmUrl()).name("auth").schemaVersion(schemaVersion)
                .build();
        realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Comment: Have you checked if the data is synced with the server? You can try connecting to the URL with Realm Studio

Comment: yes, just now tried. it was because 9080 permission issue. got it enabled now and am getting data. Thank you